# How can I walk through two files simultaneously in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have two text files that contain columnar data of the variety `position`-`value`, sorted by `position`.

Here is an example of the first file (file `A`):

```
100   1
101   1
102   0
103   2
104   1
...
```

Here is an example of the second file (`B`):

```
20    0
21    0
...
100   2
101   1
192   3
193   1
...
```

Instead of reading one of the two files into a hash table, which is prohibitive due to memory constraints, what I would like to do is walk through two files simultaneously, in a stepwise fashion.

What this means is that I would like to stream through lines of either `A` or `B` and compare `position` values.

If the two positions are equal, then I perform a calculation on the values associated with that position.

Otherwise, if the positions are not equal, I move through lines of file `A` or file `B` until the positions are equal (when I again perform my calculation) or I reach EOF of both files.

Is there a way to do this in Perl?

Comment: How many lines in each file? What is the memory constraint?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there something more subtle than just opening both files, reading lines from each, etc?

Comment: Creating a multiple-GB hash table or reading one of the two files into an array in memory is not workable - I am looking to stream both files, using their sorted property to step through either file depending on the current position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a problem one would likely stumble upon, for example database table data with keys and values. Here's an implementation of the pseudocode provided by rjp.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub read_file_line {
  my $fh = shift;

  if ($fh and my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    return [ split(/\t/, $line) ];
  }
  return;
}

sub compute {
   # do something with the 2 values
}

open(my $f1, "file1");
open(my $f2, "file2");

my $pair1 = read_file_line($f1);
my $pair2 = read_file_line($f2);

while ($pair1 and $pair2) {
  if ($pair1->[0] < $pair2->[0]) {
    $pair1 = read_file_line($f1);
  } elsif ($pair2->[0] < $pair1->[0]) {
    $pair2 = read_file_line($f2);
  } else {
    compute($pair1->[1], $pair2->[1]);
    $pair1 = read_file_line($f1);
    $pair2 = read_file_line($f2);
  }
}

close($f1);
close($f2);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: One assumes there's a `use autodie` in there as well to check those bare opens for errors. ;)

Comment: This worked well as a start, thanks! One complication is that the `while ($pair1 and $pair2)` test will cause the loop to finish as soon as either one of the files reaches EOF. My question, as framed, makes this a non-issue — however, I do need to do stuff with the other two non-pair-equality cases. So I modified `read_file_line` to return either the next line or the current line, and I keep a pair of booleans to check if the pair-line has changed. Instead of testing for EOF, I test if both lines have been unchanged by running `read_file_line`. If so, then I can safely exit the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

If the files are sorted, step through them based on which one has the lower position.

Pseudocode:

```
read Apos, Aval from A # initial values
read Bpos, Bval from B 
until eof(A) or eof(B)
  if Apos == Bpos then
    compare()
    read Apos, Aval from A # advance both files to get a new position
    read Bpos, Bval from B
  fi
  if Apos < Bpos then read Apos, Aval from A
  if Bpos < Apos then read Bpos, Bval from B
end
```

You could also use [join(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man1/join.1.html) to isolate the lines with common positions and process that at your leisure.

Answer (score 2):

For looping through files you can use the core [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) module. It represents a regular text file as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution. If the data in both files is pretty much equivalent (e.g. same number of lines), you don't really need to store in hash tables. But I thought it would be helpful in case you the data is scrambled.

Code:

```
open(f1, "<data1");
open(f2, "<data2");
# initialize hashes
%data1 = ();
%data2 = ();
while(($line1 = <f1>) and ($line2 = <f2>)){
     chomp($line1);
     chomp($line2);
     # split fields 1 and 2 into an array
     @LINE1 = split(/\t/, $line1);
     @LINE2 = split(/\t/, $line2);
     # store data into hashes
     $data1{$LINE1[0]} = $LINE1[1];
     $data2{$LINE2[0]} = $LINE2[1];
     # compare column 2
     if ($data1{$LINE2[0]} == $data2{$LINE1[0]}){
           # compute something
           $new_val = $data1{$LINE2[0]} + $data2{$LINE1[0]};
           print $LINE1[0] . "\t" . $new_val . "\n";
     } else {
           print $LINE1[0] . "\t" . $data1{$LINE1[0]} . "\n";
     }
}
```

I hope it helps and let me know if its useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering questions, try to give a brief explanation of what you did, along with the code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am new, so I assumed comments in the code would be enough.