# How can I check if contents of one file exist in another in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, compare

Requirement:-

File1 has contents like -

`ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000001,Y,,5` (this indicates there are 5 file in total in unit)

File2 has contents as `ABCD00000001`

So what i need to do is check if `ABCD00000001` from File2 exist in File1 - 
if yes{

print the output to Output.txt till it finds another ',Y,,X'}

else{ No keep checking}

Anyone? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Hi Arkadiy Output should be :- any filename from file 2 -ABCD00000001 in file1 and from Y to Y .
for ex :- file 1 structure will be :-

```
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000001,Y,,5
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000002
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000003
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000004
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000005
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000006,Y,,2
so out put should contain all line between 
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000001,Y,,5 and
```

### ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000006,Y,,2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


my $optFile = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\rgolwalkar\\Desktop\\perl_scripts\\SampleOPT1.opt";
my $tifFile = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\rgolwalkar\\Desktop\\perl_scripts\\tif_to_stitch.txt";
print "Reading OPT file now\n";
open (OPT, $optFile);
my @opt_in_array = <OPT>;
close(OPT);

foreach(@opt_in_array){
    print();
}

print "\nReading TIF file now\n";

open (TIF, $tifFile);
my @tif_in_array = <TIF>;
close(TIF);

foreach(@tif_in_array){
    print();
}
```

### so all it does it is reads 2 files "FYI -> I am new to programming"

Comment: Is Output.txt a third file or is it File1?

Comment: Hi Trey its gonna be a new file for output purpose thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the entire contents of File2 in File1? Or any "reasonable" (?) substring from File1 in File 2?

Comment: not a homework trying to minimize my work

Comment: It seems like from your example, it should also print ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000006,Y,,2 and the following line, since the first part matches as well.  Or are you just printing the first matching set and no subsequent ones?

Comment: -1 If you are asking people to spend time to help you, at least spend some time to make your question clear. What have you done so far? Why did you mark it Perl? Do you know Perl? What OS? DO you have GREP? Do you know Awk? This is fairly trivial to solve but you need to help yourself too...

Comment: Is your problem similar to the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498937/how-can-i-walk-through-two-files-simultaneously-in-perl ?

Comment: @Brian -> I read it and since i was not clear about i asked the question -i am new to perl 
@Drewk - i have explained as much as i can - if i knew about Sed and Awk and Perl well enough - i definitely wouldn't have to ask this question -
People its ok if this is not the forum for guys new in programming - please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll bite (partially)...

First general comments. Use strict and -w are good, but you are not checking for the results of open or explicitly stating your desired read/write mode.

The contents of your OPT file kinda sorta looks like it is CSV and the second field looks like a Windows path, true? If so, use the appropriate library from CPAN to parse CSV and verify your file names. Misery and pain can be the result otherwise...

As Ether stated earlier, you need to read the file OPT then match the field you want. If the first file is CSV, first you need to parse it without destroying your file names.

Here is a small snippet that will parse your OPT file. At this point, all it does is print the fields, but you can add logic to match to the other file easily. Just read ([slurp](http://www.sysarch.com/Perl/slurp_article.html)) the entire second file into a single string and match with your chosen field from the first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
my @opt_fields;


while (<DATA>) {
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        push @opt_fields, [ $csv->fields() ];
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}


foreach my $ref (@opt_fields) {
#   foreach my $field (@$ref) { print "$field\n"; }
    print "The anon array: @$ref\n";
    print "Use to match?: $ref->[0]\n";
    print "File name?: $ref->[1]\n";
}

__DATA__
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000001,Y,,5
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000002
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000003
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000004
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000005
ABCD00000001,\some\some1\ABCD00000006,Y,,2
```

Comment: @Drewk - thanks a lot for helping me out on this - i am trying it now - once done will paste the code with result

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking up your problem into discrete steps.  It seems that you need to do this (although your question is not very clear):

- open file1 for reading
- open file2 for reading
- read file1, line by line:

  - for each line in file1, check if there is particular content anywhere in file2

Which part are you having difficulty with? What code have you got so far? Once you have a line in memory, you can compare it to another string using a regular expression, or perhaps a simpler form of comparison.

Comment: hmm just want help with :- 
how to print from Y to Y i have pasted the desired output in the main comment.

Comment: @golwalkar => simply posting desired output isn't good enough.  post some sample code that you think should work.  Ether's answer is a "teach a man to fish" type answer.

Comment: ok doing the same in the main code .
Confession :-  just was able to read the files thats all.

Comment: i have added the code and yes Esther it does nothing except reading the two files :(